# Error: Unable to initialize main class FileChooser_1 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Stage

Tags: java, javafx, noclassdeffounderror

Here I have written the following code. I can't run the program, and the error mentioned below keeps appearing. I tried many probable solutions but in vain.

```
import java.beans.EventHandler;
import java.io.File;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.*;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.*;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.scene.text.*;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FileChooser_1 extends Application {

// launch the application
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        try {

            // title
            stage.setTitle("Filechooser");

            //File chooser create
            FileChooser file_chooser = new FileChooser();

            // define Label
            Label lab = new Label("select file");

            // Button new
            Button b = new Button("open dialog");

            // create Event Handler
            EventHandler<ActionEvent> eve
                = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                public void handle(ActionEvent e) {

                    // get file
                    File file = file_chooser.showOpenDialog(stage);

                    if (file != null) {

                        lab.setText(file.getAbsolutePath()
                            + " selected");
                    }
                }
            };

            b.setOnAction(event);

            // create Button
            Button b1 = new Button("save");

            // Event Handler
            EventHandler<ActionEvent> eve1
                = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                public void handle(ActionEvent e) {

                    // get file
                    File file = file_chooser.showSaveDialog(stage);

                    if (file != null) {
                        lab.setText(file.getAbsolutePath()
                            + " selected");
                    }
                }
            };

            b1.setOnAction(eve1);

            // VBox
            VBox vbox = new VBox(30, label, button, button1);

            // set Alignment
            vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

            // create scene
            Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 800, 500);

            // scene
            stage.setScene(scene);

            stage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

// Main Method
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class FileChooser_1
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Stage
```

It will be really nice if you can help me with this.

Comment: `java.beans.EventHandler`should be [`javafx.event.EventHandler`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.base/javafx/event/EventHandler.html).

Comment: Only import classes you use.  When logging errors, log the full stack trace `exception.printStackTrace()`.  Add the full stack trace to your question formatted as code.

Comment: Edit the question, add the command used to run the program, formatted as code.

Comment: Can you explain how you use the r.Java-file which you have tagged your question with?  That is for Android development, not JavaFX.

Answer (score 4):

With some attention to detail, your code works. In particular, especially when just starting out,

- Use Java [naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html).
- Use meaningful names; for example, instead of `Button b`, try `Button openButton`.
- When using detailed comments, keep them up to date; note how meaningful names make some comments superfluous.
- Use constants for consistency.
- As @jewelsea notes, your program imports `java.beans.EventHandler`; it should import [`javafx.event.EventHandler`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.base/javafx/event/EventHandler.html).
- As @jewelsea notes, "Only import classes you use."
- Let the layout do the work.
- I can't explain the error in your question; I see errors related to the incorrect `import` for `EventHandler`. If you're using an IDE, it may be reporting errors from a different compilation unit. When in doubt, do a clean build, move the code to a new file, or move to a different development environment, e.g. the command line. As a concrete example, this simple [VersionCheck](https://gist.github.com/trashgod/c3e0fa8480b11f93b9ab08e597a45a5a) illustrates both a minimal `ant` script, invoked as `ant run`, and a simple shell script, invoked as `.run.sh`:

  ```
    #!/bin/sh
    JFX="--module-path /Users/Shared/javafx-sdk-17.0.1/lib --add-modules ALL-MODULE-PATH"
    javac $JFX *.java && java $JFX VersionCheck
  ```

[image]

```
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import java.io.File;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FileChooser1 extends Application {

    private static final int PADDING = 32;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        // title
        stage.setTitle("FileChooser");
        //File chooser create
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        // define Label
        Label label = new Label("Select a file to open or save:");
        // open Button
        Button openButton = new Button("Open");
        // open Event Handler
        EventHandler<ActionEvent> openHandler = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                // get file name
                File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stage);
                if (file != null) {
                    label.setText(file.getName() + " selected");
                }
            }
        };
        openButton.setOnAction(openHandler);
        // create save button
        Button saveButton = new Button("Save");
        // save Event Handler
        EventHandler<ActionEvent> saveHandler = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                // save file
                File file = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(stage);
                if (file != null) {
                    label.setText(file.getName() + " selected");
                }
            }
        };
        saveButton.setOnAction(saveHandler);
        // VBox
        VBox vBox = new VBox(PADDING, label, openButton, saveButton);
        // set Alignment
        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        vBox.setPadding(new Insets(PADDING));
        // create scene
        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox);
        // scene
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```