# Is there a method similar to getSelectedFile in JavaFX that returns a File?

Tags: java, swing, javafx, fxml, filechooser

Is there a method similar to `getSelectedFile` in JavaFX that returns a `File`? I have tried this code now trying to perfect the commented out `//fileToSend[0]`

```
@FXML
private void chooseButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

    FileChooser JFileChooser = new FileChooser();
    JFileChooser.setTitle("Choose a file to send");
    
    Stage stage = (Stage) anchorPane.getScene().getWindow();
    File file = JFileChooser.showOpenDialog(stage);

    if (file != null) {
        //fileToSend[0] = JFileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        fileName.setText("File Name " + file.getName());
    }

}
```

Comment: I don’t understand why your code mixes JavaFX and Swing.

Comment: Fascinating! Your code is pure JavaFX yet you declare a variable whose name is that of a _Swing_ class. I am referring to `JFileChooser`. Your commented line of code will not compile since class `javafx.stage.FileChooser` does not have a `getSelectedFile` method. In any case, you already have the selected file in this line of your code: `File file = JFileChooser.showOpenDialog(stage);`. Also, if `fileToSend` is a variable, I could not find its declaration in the code in your question. Did I miss something?

Comment: Well sorry for the naming conventions, I missed that part actually :). I am making the project in fx but couldn't find a similar fx method so went for the swing to show the method which I am looking for.
And the code compiled it just opens a swing dialogbox in a fx program .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Swing component [`JFileChooser`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) offers [`getSelectedFile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#getSelectedFile()) and [`getSelectedFiles()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#getSelectedFiles()), which returns an array "of selected files if the file chooser is set to allow multiple selection." In contrast, the JavaFX control [`FileChooser`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html) returns a single `File` from  [`showOpenDialog()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html#showOpenDialog(javafx.stage.Window)), and it returns a `List<File>` from [`showOpenMultipleDialog()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html#showOpenMultipleDialog(javafx.stage.Window)).

Given a `FileChooser` instance, you can obtain the list of `selected` files like this:

```
FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
List<File> selected = fileChooser.showOpenMultipleDialog(stage);
```

You can get the first `selected` file like this:

```
System.out.println(selected.get(0));
```

You can iterate through them like this:

```
selected.forEach(file -> System.out.println(file.getName() + " selected"));
```

The complete example below is based on this related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71288497/230513):

[image]

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71362723/230513 */
public class FileChooserDemo extends Application {

    private static final int PADDING = 16;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("FileChooserDemo");
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        Label label = new Label("Select one or more files:");
        TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
        textArea.setPrefColumnCount(16);
        textArea.setPrefRowCount(4);
        Button singleButton = new Button("Select a File");
        singleButton.setOnAction((ActionEvent t) -> {
            File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stage);
            if (file != null) {
                textArea.clear();
                textArea.appendText(file.getName());
            }
        });
        Button multiButton = new Button("Select Files");
        multiButton.setOnAction((ActionEvent t) -> {
            List<File> selected = fileChooser.showOpenMultipleDialog(stage);
            if (selected != null) {
                textArea.clear();
                selected.forEach(file -> textArea.appendText(file.getName() + "\n"));
            }
        });
        VBox vBox = new VBox(PADDING, label, singleButton, multiButton, textArea);
        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        vBox.setPadding(new Insets(PADDING));
        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```