# run javafx from python and get output

Tags: python, javafx, google-colaboratory

i have a javafx gui programe which work fine in windows, I can run this .jar using python in my local PC and get output, but when try to do same using google colab I got this error

my JavaFX GUI file named: `ex4.jar`

code:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
p = Popen(['java', '-jar', 'ex4.jar' , '3'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)

for line in p.stdout:
  print ( line)
```

I got error:

```
b'Error: Could not find or load main class frontend.App\n'
b'Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application\n'
```

Comment: In this context, I usually add the _module_ options explicitly, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71288497/230513).

Comment: sorry, i didn't understand this steps, my code run in windows correct as a .jar file, but can not open this JavaFX .jar file at google colab

Comment: Sorry, I don't know where to put the required `java` options in [tag:google-colaboratory].