# Unexpected error running gluonfx nativerun target

Tags: javafx, gluon, gluonfx

I am failing to run a native desktop build on a macOS (M2), command:

```
mvn gluonfx:nativerun
```

I am using the HelloFx example from the gluon samples project, although have the same issue with independent projects I have tried creating.

I am using a Gluon graalvm:

```
graalvm-svm-java17-darwin-m1-gluon-22.1.0.1-Final
```

The following commands execute correctly:

```
mvn gluonfx:run
mvn gluonfx:runagent
mvn gluonfx:build
```

But:

```
mvn gluonfx:native run
```

results in a window appearing with

```
HelloFX quit unexpectedly
```

and the following logged:

```
[Tue Feb 28 15:02:27 GMT 2023][INFO] ==================== RUN TASK ====================
[Tue Feb 28 15:02:27 GMT 2023][INFO] [SUB] 2023-02-28 15:02:27.538 HelloFX[1951:40168] Starting Gluon VM...
[Tue Feb 28 15:02:27 GMT 2023][INFO] [SUB] Feb 28, 2023 3:02:27 PM com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl startup
[Tue Feb 28 15:02:27 GMT 2023][INFO] [SUB] WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @4563e9ab'
[Tue Feb 28 15:02:27 GMT 2023][INFO] [SUB] 2023-02-28 15:02:27.632 HelloFX[1951:40139] *** Assertion failure in -[_NSTrackingAreaAKViewHelper removeTrackingRect:], _NSTrackingAreaAKManager.m:1602
[Tue Feb 28 15:02:27 GMT 2023][SEVERE] Process run until end failed with result: 139
Check the log files under /Users/xxxx/Downloads/gluon-samples-master/HelloFX/target/gluonfx/aarch64-darwin/gvm/log
And please check https://docs.gluonhq.com/ for more information.
[Tue Feb 28 15:02:27 GMT 2023][INFO] Logging process [run until end] to file: /Users/xxxx/Downloads/gluon-samples-master/HelloFX/target/gluonfx/log/process-run until end-1677596547634.log
```

Any advice on how to proceed much appreciated.

Comment: I should add, I am using the HelloFx example from the gluon samples project, although have the same issue with independent projects I have tried creating.

Comment: Can you try adding `<javafxStaticSdkVersion>21-ea+5</javafxStaticSdkVersion>` to the GluonFX plugin's configuration?

Comment: See the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74630535/1271785) related to the M2 (jewelsea's comments, specifically). You may need to run Java 19 which supports the M2.

Comment: Thank you both.  Jose's suggestion has resolved the issue, but will review the link posted by pfurbacher as well.  Thanks again.