# Error: Could not find or load main class ... Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx, executable-jar

Can't open an executable jar from Maven project in IntelliJ

Hello everyone

So I am currently working on a Maven project using JavaFX interface on the IDE IntelliJ. Everything works fine except when I try to export the project in an executable jar file.

Everytime I try the "java -jar myproject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" command in the terminal it shows this error

`Error: Could not find or load main class mypackage.myproject.Main Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application`

I also tried to generate a .jar with artifact in project structure but when I try to open it, I get another error which is :

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
    at java.base/sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:340)
    at java.base/sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:282)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:327)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:239)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:760)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.ensureInitialization(JarFile.java:1058)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JavaUtilJarAccessImpl.ensureInitialization(JavaUtilJarAccessImpl.java:72)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getManifest(URLClassPath.java:883)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:848)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:495)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:474)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.loadMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:790)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:685)
```

My JDK is version 19.
In the MANIFEST FILE, the Main-Class is specified.

Here is my pom.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>mypackage</groupId>
    <artifactId>PearCar</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>PearCar</name>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>AsposeJavaAPI</id>
            <name>Aspose Java API</name>
            <url>https://repository.aspose.com/repo/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.9.0</junit.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>19-ea+7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>19-ea+7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.bootstrapfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrapfx-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.27</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox-tools</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.27</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>io</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>layout</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>forms</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfa</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdftest</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.cssbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdf2dom</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aspose</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspose-pdf</artifactId>
            <version>21.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20220924</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>mypackage.myproject.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>19</source>
                    <target>19</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>mypackage.myproject/mypackage.myproject.Main</mainClass>
                            <launcher>app</launcher>
                            <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                            <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

here is my module-info.java file :

```
module mypackage.myproject {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;

    requires org.kordamp.bootstrapfx.core;
    requires java.sql;
    requires org.apache.pdfbox;
    requires java.desktop;
    requires layout;
    requires kernel;
    requires io;
    //requires aspose.pdf;
    requires net.sf.cssbox.pdf2dom;
    requires aspose.pdf;
    requires forms;
    requires commons.lang3;


    opens mypackage.myproject to javafx.fxml;
    exports mypackage.myproject;
    exports Controller;
    opens Controller to javafx.fxml;
}
```

Thank you !

Comment: What happens if you specify the `--module-path` etc., for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71288497/230513).

Comment: Your options: jlink it (recommended) using the maven-javafx-plugin (it is modular, so that may work), if it doesn't work then jpackage it.  If you really want to just deploy a jar (not recommended), then use the [unsupported shade config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653836/maven-shade-javafx-runtime-components-are-missing) for a single jar, or, better provide an unshaded jar for your app and place the dependent libraries in a lib directory, run with module settings like trashgod's sample but for all your modules, not just javafx modules, and zip everything up for distribution.

Comment: Also note that an executable [modular jar](https://jenkov.com/tutorials/java/modules.html#setting-the-jar-main-class) does not use the class path and main class settings in the manifest which might be used for an executable non-modular jar.

Comment: I added in VM options in 'Run > configuration > Jar Application > MyAppliaction.jar'

'--module-path "mypath\openjfx-19_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-19\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml'

and the error message is gone when I run the jar file in IntelliJ !

However, I still have it when I try to open it from the Terminal with the 'java -jar' and the 'java -cp'

So it solved the issue only in the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution !

So if you are using IntelliJ with a Maven Project, you have to add :

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>mypackage.myproject.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                    <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

and run the exe jar in the terminal with the cmd :

```
java --module-path "mypath\openjfx-19_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-19\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar myproject-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

It worked for me !

Hope it helps :)

Comment: it works thanks