# How can I determine what version of JavaFX libraries I'm using in a given IntelliJ project?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I have a problem with an IntelliJ project which I'd like to raise on this forum, but before I do so, I want to gather all the information I can about my environment.

MacOS 13.0.1 (Ventura)
IntelliJ Community Edition 2021.2
JDK 15.0.2
... but I'm also using JavaFX libraries, and I presume it will help to say what version they're at.

Comment: If you're using Maven or Gradle, it should be apparent from your pom.xml or gradle config file. Otherwise you can do `System.out.println(System.getProperty("javafx.version"));`

Comment: A simple `VersionCheck` is cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71288497/230513).

Comment: I do recommend using either Maven or Gradle as a build tool (you can set that up using the [new JavaFX project wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74764217/error-javafx-runtime-components-are-missing-with-intellij-idea-maven-and-jdk)).  Then the configuration is in the build tool's project definition, which can be checked into source control, easily updated, and automatically synchronized with any major Java IDE, obviating the need for error-prone manual downloads of the JavaFX SDK, configuration of compile and runtime module options or manually adding libraries to an IDE project.

Comment: Maven is what I get 'out of the box' when I create a JavaFX project; I'm not au fait with the differences between that and Gradle, but Maven works for me.